# Modifying an SVG animateTransform at end-of-repeat-loop

Tags: javascript, svg, dom-events, smil

I'm trying to make an object rotate faster and faster as time goes on, and I'm having trouble having an event fire every time the animation repeats itself. SVG/SMIL's [repeatEvent](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#InterfaceTimeEvent) seems to be what I need, but in the following code, `onSpinEnd()` doesn't appear to be called at all. What am I doing wrong?

```
    <path id='coloredPart' d='…'>
        <animateTransform
            id='spin'
            attributeName='transform'
            begin='0s'
            dur='5s'
            type='rotate'
            from='0 0 0'
            to='-360 0 0'
            repeatCount='indefinite'
        />
    </path>

    <script>  <![CDATA[
        var spin = document.getElementById('spin');
        var onSpinEnd = function() {
            var intPart = 0;
            intPart = parseInt(spin.getAttribute('dur')[0].slice(0, -1));
            console.log(intPart);
            if (intPart > 1) --intPart;
            spin.setAttribute('dur', intPart.toString() + 's');
        };
        spin.addEventListener('repeatEvent', onSpinEnd, false)
        ]]>   
    </script>
```

As it turns out, `[0].slice(0, -1))` won't give me "16" from "16s"; `.slice(0, -1))` will. That line should read:

```
intPart = parseInt(spin.getAttribute('dur').slice(0, -1));
```

Comment: Apparently repeatEvent isn't firing but I can't find out why. Anyway I must point out that your `slice` is wrong, you can't use negative indexing.

Comment: Actually, [you can use negative indexing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the slice is for. This seems to work on Firefox.

```
var onSpinEnd = function() {
    var spin = document.getElementById('spin');
    var intPart = 0;
    intPart = parseInt(spin.getAttribute('dur')[0]);
    console.log(intPart);
    if (intPart > 1) --intPart;
    spin.setAttribute('dur', intPart.toString() + 's');
};
```

Additionally, as far as I know only Opera and Firefox currently fire SMIL events.

Comment: Only Firefox and Opera, eh? Thanks!